# Prove that u and v are in W.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let W be a subspace of the vector space V.  **u** and **v** are elements of V such that **u + v** and **u - v** are in W. I need to prove that **u** and **v** are in W.

I think I can use this theorem, but I'm not quite sure if I can apply it in the reverse direction.

If W is a nonempty subset of a vector space V, then W is a subspace of V if and only if the following closure conditions hold. 
1. If **u** and **v** are in W, then **u + v** is in W 
2. If **u** is in W and c is any scalar, then c**u** is in W.

Comment: "if and only if" means that you can use it in the reverse direction, namely if conditions 1 and 2 hold, then if W is nonempty subset of V, W is subspace of V. You don't need the reverse direction though, because the question already assumed that W is a subspace of V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $2u= (u+v)+(u-v)$, then use vector space property of $W$...